# d * e mod phi == 1 not always true for RSA key pair

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

When generating RSA keys with Bouncycastle with following program (see below) why is

d * e mod phi == 1  where phi := (p - 1) * (q - 1)

**not** true in most of the cases (value of `check1`)?

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateCrtKey;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class TestRsaKey1 {

    private static Provider BC_PROVIDER;

    static {
        BC_PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.insertProviderAt(BC_PROVIDER, 1);
    } // static

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(512);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            boolean check0, check1;
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
            BCRSAPrivateCrtKey kPriv = (BCRSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate();
            BigInteger n, e, d, p, q;
            n = kPriv.getModulus();
            e = kPriv.getPublicExponent();
            d = kPriv.getPrivateExponent();
            p = kPriv.getPrimeP();
            q = kPriv.getPrimeQ();
            
            // phi := (p - 1) * (q - 1)
            BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)); // phi := (p - 1) * (q - 1)
            
            // following check p * q == n ?  is true in 100% of cases
            check0 = n.equals(p.multiply(q));   

            // following check d * e mod phi == 1 ?  is true only in ca. 30% of cases
            check1 = BigInteger.ONE.equals(d.multiply(e).mod(phi));

            System.out.println(check0 + " " + check1);
        }
    } // main

} // class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the key derivation (like practically all modern implementations) uses the Carmichael totient function *lambda(n) = lcm(p-1, q-1)*, instead of the Euler totient function *phi(n) = (p-1)*(q-1)*.

If the test is performed with the Carmichael totient function, the condition *d*e = 1 (mod lambda(n))* is fulfilled for *all* tests:

```
BigInteger lambda = lcm(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
boolean check2 = BigInteger.ONE.equals(d.multiply(e).mod(lambda)); // d * e mod lambda == 1 ?  <-- true for ALL cases
System.out.println(check0 + " " + check2);
```

with ([here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lcm-of-two-large-numbers/))

```
private static BigInteger lcm(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    BigInteger mul = a.multiply(b);
    BigInteger gcd = a.gcd(b);
    BigInteger lcm = mul.divide(gcd);
    return lcm;
}
```

References for Euler vs. Carmichael totient function, e.g.:
[RSA (cryptosystem) - Key generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation)
[Do Carmichael's and Euler's totient functions in RSA generate the same keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70624)
[Main purpose for Carmichael's Function in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54280)
[Why do we need Euler's totient function φ(N) in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33676)
[lcm versus phi in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29591)